# Проблема с путями / java

Tags: пути, java

Есть проблема, она постоянно надоедает.
Суть проблемы: 
(это в самом проекте)

- `user.dir`, получаю путь к файлу, потом делаю так `UserDir + "/src/" + pathJson`
- `pathJson` - текстовый файл, он внутри программы
  такой путь `/home/jashka/IdeaProjects/Catalog + "/src/" + pathJson`

(на рабочем столе файл `Catalog.jar`)
когда я собираю jar файл в Idea, потом помещаю его на рабочий стол и запускаю, 
то вот такая ошибка
`/home/jashka/Рабочий стол/src/pathToJson.txt` (а должно что-то быть типа `/home/jashka/Рабочий стол/Catalog.jar/src/pathToJson.txt`)

Как это решить?

Comment: С каких это пор можно просто так достать ресурс из архива не распаковывая его? @woesss вам правильно подсказывает, что вы работаете с ресурсом, доступным из classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что бы прочитать внутренний ресурс проще использовать:

```
 getClass().getResourceAsStream("/pathToJson.txt")
```

PS: Ах, да! Папка "src" не идёт в билд. Исправил ответ - так должно работать. Вы можете открыть собранный JAR архиватором и посмотреть что где лежит: путь к файлу внутри JAR-архива - это и есть правильный путь для `ClassLoader` и его метода `getResourceAsStream()`